# Dropwizard @UnitOfWork: Large number of SET autocommit=1/0; commit calls where there is no transaction to run

Tags: mysql, hibernate, load-testing, ehcache, dropwizard

My App (https://github.com/atulsm/config-service) is a simple config service which stores/retrieves config key/vals from db and consists of the following.

1. Dropwizard
2. Hibernate
3. Hibernate EHCache
4. Mysql

I have Mysql general log enabled and when i look into it while running a [load test](https://github.com/atulsm/config-service/blob/master/src/test/java/com/atul/configservice/api/IntegrationTestBucketService.java) of simple get(), this is the only thing i see in the log which fills in the entire logs.

2019-08-28T11:36:12.003158Z   295 Query SET autocommit=0

2019-08-28T11:36:12.003318Z   295 Query commit

2019-08-28T11:36:12.003425Z   295 Query SET autocommit=1

2019-08-28T11:36:12.003834Z   295 Query SET autocommit=0

2019-08-28T11:36:12.004005Z   295 Query commit

2019-08-28T11:36:12.004105Z   295 Query SET autocommit=1

2019-08-28T11:36:12.004481Z   295 Query SET autocommit=0

2019-08-28T11:36:12.004646Z   295 Query commit

2019-08-28T11:36:12.004762Z   295 Query SET autocommit=1

Question:

1. Since no query got executed and the data was provided from the second level cache, my expectation was that there will be no interaction with Mysql
2. Any idea why this is happening? Is there a way to disable it.
3. My QPS is currently ~800. I am hoping that if i can disable these commit calls, it would improve dramatically.

### EDIT

Problem seems to be with @UnitOfWork. I removed the entire DAO call and replaced it with a dummy object, still i see DB Operations !

```
Bucket dummy = new Bucket();
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
@UnitOfWork
public Bucket getBucket(@PathParam("bucketName") String bucketName){
    //return BucketService.INSTANCE.getBucket(bucketName);
    return dummy;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was addressed by disabling transaction in get operations using @UnitOfWork(transactional = false).

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
@UnitOfWork(transactional = false)
public Bucket getBucket(@PathParam("bucketName") String bucketName){
    return BucketService.INSTANCE.getBucket(bucketName);
}
```